# Get all parameters from a specific URL

Tags: python, string, urllib, url-parsing

How can I enumerate all the parameters from a specific link using Python?

For example:

My target URL:
`http://www.examplesite.com/index.php?action=<some_value>`
and it has got 4 parameters associated with it (not known to me):

```
http://www.examplesite.com/index.php?action=<some_value>
http://www.examplesite.com/index.php?fetch=<some_value>
http://www.examplesite.com/index.php?enter=<some_value>
http://www.examplesite.com/index.php?details_of=<some_value>
```

What I want is a list of those parameters:

```
action
fetch
enter
details_of
```

More specifically, my python code should take input of the URL only and return the parameters associated with that specific URL.

Eg-

```
My input: 
http ://www.examplesite.com/index.php?action=<some_value>

Output:

The parameters are:
action
fetch
enter
details_of
```

So how do I identify the all the parameters from that specific URL? Is there any ready-made specific module for getting this?

I hope this makes everything clear :)

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise `urllib.parse` from the standard library:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

x = 'http://www.examplesite.com/index.php?action=<some_value>'

parse_res = urlparse(x)

res_full = parse_res.query                # 'action=<some_value>'
res_part = parse_res.query.split('=')[0]  # 'action'
```